# Round off seconds in date bash command to lower bound

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I have a date command to display Hours Minutes and Seconds, which is something like

```
date -u +"%H%M%S" | cut -c 1-6
```

It will show something, for instance `155344`. I need the output to round off to the lower bound always, so for the above example I need it to be `155340`.

Even if the above command produces `155349` my output should display lowest bound `155340` not the `155350`.

Waiting to get enlightened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the output, integer divide by 10, and then multiply by 10, so so if you had that value stored as `output`:

```
output=$(( $output / 10 ))
output=$(( $output * 10 ))
```

`$(())` is integer arithmetic in bash, and truncates rather than rounds.

This can be written as one line with

```
$(( $(date -u +"%H%M%S" | cut -c 1-6) / 10 * 10 ))
```

Comment: This will need adjustment for various times between midnight and 10am; the leading 0 in the timestamp will cause it to be interpreted as an octal number.

Comment: Consider what happens at `082118` or `072117`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you basically want to replace the last character of a string with `0`, you could do it with [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
$ timestamp=$(date -u +"%H%M%S")
$ echo "$timestamp"
161333
$ echo "${timestamp%?}0"
161330
```

You also don't need `cut`, as the output of your `date` command should always be six characters long anyway.

Comment: That's a good hack as well. I figured out that `$(date -u +"%H%M%S" | cut -c 1-5)0` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

`$(date -u +"%H%M%S" | cut -c 1-5)0`

This works as well, but it's a shady hack to fix it.

Comment: This is less of a hack than performing base-10 arithmetic on a string that isn't really a base-10 number.

Comment: Agreed @chepner